# Improve face tracking quality

Tags: video-tracking

Currently I using dlib correlation tracker method, but it only track the bounding box of face alignment, and it does not work so well. So I wonder does any way to track all the face alignments like eye, nose and mouth etc.?

Comment: why do you want to track?  Just calculate the 68 landmarks for every frame.  That is much faster. http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html

Comment: @azmath i have try dlib get frontal face detector, but it does not work well especially for slightly side faces. So I use this mtcnn face detection. The detection speed is much slower than dlib, so I skip some frame and apply tracking for it. I just thought that track all face alignment might improve the tracking quality.
https://github.com/pangyupo/mxnet_mtcnn_face_detection

Comment: didn't you try dllib's  mmod detector?  dlib has two detectors.  the `mmod` and `hog` .  hog is available in python but `mmod` is only available in `cpp`.  It is much robust and accurate.  http://dlib.net/dnn_mmod_face_detection_ex.cpp.html